# Javascript set image on date else hide div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a need to have an image change on a certain date (not day of week but a date e.g. August 18th, August 25th, September 3rd etc).

Here's the div in question:

```
<div id="matchday">
    <img id="home" src="css/images/teams/home.png">
    <span class="verses">V</span>
    <img id="away" src="css/images/teams/away1.png">
</div>
```

My goal is to have the away img change on the known date of the match to away2.png, away3.png ... away20.png etc.

To complicate things, rather than having a default "away" image, it would be nice to only show the div on a matchday (one of the known dates used to set the image)

Comment: You'll probably want to look into JavaScript's Date object for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yourDay` is a day in a month (1-31), `yourMonth` is a month (0-11):

```
if(getDate()==yourDay && getMonth()==yourMonth){
document.getElementById("away").src="away93485989273958293.png" //any awayN.png you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went down this route as the image names are generated by someone else, and it's possible a match would be reschedule so rather than have to resequence the list of away images, i can just use the team name (thats how the images are provided)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a built in Date object, you can use it like this `var date = new Date()`. For a nice tutorial, check this out: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manipulate-time-and-date-values-with-javascripts-date-object/ or use the excellent library Moment: http://momentjs.com/. The approach would then be to instantiate a date object; 'var date = new Date()' and use this in a if / switch statement to display the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0):

```
   imgSrc= new Array();
    for(i=1;i<=20;i++) {
        imgSrc[i]=i+".png";  //Let the name of your image files be 1.png,2.png etc.
    }

if(getDate()==yourDay && getMonth()==yourMonth){
    document.getElementById("away").src=imgSrc[i];
}
```

Built on [nicael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael)'s Answer

Answer (score 0):

Ar your css you should have something like this:

```
#matchday {
   display: none,
   ...
}
```

Using javascript and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   //specify your date
   var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);

   //compare current date with your selected date
   if($.now() == d.getTime()) {

      //display your div (use the proper value, the one you need to fit your design)
      $("#matchday").css("display", "block");
   }
});
```